# Return a value based on 3 different criteria not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[The image includes the criteria, the source data and the desired data output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQXps.jpg)I am working on a sheet to return "time in transit" based on origin zipcode, destination zipcode and a shipping code (4,3,2,1). I tried several `index/match`methods, and I have also made a unique value for each combination to try a `vlookup` formula. I have searched all over and cannot find out what is wrong with my formula.

The formula I have for the index/match formula is

`{=INDEX($H$3:$M$4517,MATCH(1,(H:H=O3)*(I:I=P3)*(K:K=Q3),0),6)}`

I have asterisk between the 3 different criteria in there, but they're not showing up in the type. The data includes the "transit time" value for the origin and destination combo of 84104 and 00544, but in the results for the `index/match` formula, the transit times should be, in descending order, 5,3,2,1., however the results are 2,1,0,0. Is there something wrong with my formula or the formatting of the data?

Comment: I have 2 questions that may make this question easier to answer. 1) Can you re-upload your screenshot to include the row/column labels? It's hard to interpret your formula without being able to see which cells are which. 2) Must you have all of your data split into separate tables, or can you combine it into a single table? It might make your formulas easier.

Comment: @user2800 I reuploaded the photo. I am trying to figure out how to combine the data, "criteria" has about 4x as many rows as "data" does, and I have to extrapolate the missing data from "data" and put it into "criteria". Criteria contains alot more postal codes than "data" does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard for me to figure out the right formula with two separate tables, so for the moment, I'm going to just pretend you've combined your two tables together and that the combined data is in columns H-M.

Generic Formula (See link: https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria):

```
{=INDEX(range1,MATCH(1,(A1=range2)*(B1=range3)*(C1=range4),0))}
```

Putting your formula in R3:

For the INDEX portion, you want to use the range that contains the possible values to return, which is just column M.

```
=INDEX(M3:M4517,MATCH(.....
```

You want to MATCH the values in O3, P3, and Q3 to H3, I3, and K3, respectively:

```
=INDEX(M3:M4517,MATCH(1,(O3=H3:H4517)*(P3=I3:I4517)*(Q3=K3:K4517),...
```

Finally, add the 0 argument at the end of the formula and enter as an array.

```
{=INDEX(M3:M4517,MATCH(1,(O3=H3:H4517)*(P3=I3:I4517)*(Q3=K3:K4517),0))}
```

Try that and let me know if it works correctly in matching your Data table; I'm not an expert on array formulas. If so, we can add in the Criteria data next.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for your help, this has solved my problem completely, and it has given me insight into how excel works and how to plan my formulas, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**I've successfully produced the desire results using your Formula, with little modification, has solved the issue**.

[image]

- Enter this Array (CSE) Formula in Cell `Q2`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill it down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(G:L,MATCH(1,(G:G=N2)*(H:H=O2)*(J:J=P2),0),6),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Instead of `INDEX($H$3:$M$4517` I've used 
  `INDEX(G:L` and rest parts are similar.
- You may use Absolute reference also.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*